# how do I open a SQL database from work on my home machine?

Tags: sql-server

I  am new to SQL.
I successfully installed SQL server on a win10 PRO box at home.
I connected to a SQL server instance on my home machine.
I can create a database and work on it as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/quickstarts/ssms-connect-query-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

However, I want to investigate an already created database from another machine at my office.
I want to be able to create custom reports from that data.
This other database is from an application that creates and manages a schedule.
It runs on a winPro box as well but I cannot really experiment on it while it is in use.

I have copied the DATA folder from that other machine running SQL server to the desktop of my home machine.

How do I open it ?

I tried a real noob thing--
Turned off sql server (in services) , replaced the DATA folder in here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.LYTEC_SQL\MSSQL\DATA
with the DATA folder I copied to the desktop.
Restarting sql server gives me an error.

Clearly I dont know what I am doing.
Is there a link somewhere that will explain to me what to do so I can start this other database to explore it (names of the fields,etc) and write reports?

Comment: you'll need to attach a database if you've just copied the raw files, or restore a backup if you've taken a backup of the old files.

Comment: You probably just killed your instance by replacing the `master` database and now need to reinstall SQL Server. You are supposed to use `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH`

Comment: I restored the original DATA folder (which I had saved). Then I  tried to follow this: https://www.sqlshack.com/move-a-sql-database-using-the-detach-and-attach-method/

Comment: I put the DATA folder I am trying to attach in the root drive (C://DATA). When I get to running the script in the above link I get: Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 3
Unable to open the physical file "C:\DATA\master.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 7, Line 3
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Comment: so i checked the properties of the DATA folder and unchecked the 'read only'checkbox. I reran the script and was told I could not use the same names. I went back to the attach databases window and changed the names slightly under the 'attach as' column. Now 'master' under the attach as column was 'masterL' I reran the script AGAIN and got:

Comment: Converting database 'masterL' from version 661 to the current version 904.
Database 'masterL' running the upgrade step from version 661 to version 668.
...
Database 'masterL' running the upgrade step from version 676 to version 677.
Database 'masterL' running the upgrade step from version 677 to version 679.
Msg 5570, Level 23, State 3, Line 3
FILESTREAM Failed to find the garbage collection table.

Completion time: 2021-02-21T10:29:34.8732105-05:00

I truncated the message since it wouldnt fit in the comment block here.

But nothing new appears in object explorer.